# Подскажите библиотеки где можно найти подобный плагин

Tags: carousel

Доброго времени суток. Сейчас верстаю сайт, но не могу найти подобного плана карусель. Я искал в Bootstrap и других css-библиотеках. Где можно ещё поискать?

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvdCd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую вот эти два, там есть куча настроек, всегда что-то из них использую:

1. Slick - http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
2. Swiper - http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WXO5PMaQwy4